# ES6, parameter destructuring with default values. A way to write less

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

Ho can I avoid to write all fields `with = ""`?

```
const defaultPlayer = {
        name: "",
        surname: "",
        age: "",
        skill: ""
      }
// ...
mapPropsToValues = ({ player }) => player || defaultPlayer
```

Is there in javascript that I can use to avoid write all the time `= ""`?

I mean, if I already know that defalut value of every field is `""` (empty string) how can I do instead of write every field explicitly?

Comment: like saving `""` in a variable?? or what do you mean?

Comment: Well those *are* the default values that you want, no reason not to explicitly write them down. Also most likely those aren't even all strings, maybe the default `age` should rather be the integer `0` and the default `skill` should be `null`.

Comment: No, I mean, if I already know that defalut value of every field is `""` (empty string) how can I do instead of write every field explicitly?

Comment: @JohnSam Unless you have a list of all field(name)s somewhere, you will need to write them down explicitly.

Comment: FYI, your map function will take something like `[{ player: somePlayer}]` and map it to `[somePlayer]` or `[defaultPlayer]`. Not sure if that is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a `with` block and a `Proxy` object and `eval`:

```js
let defaultPlayer;
with (new Proxy({}, {
  has(o, key) {
    try { eval(key); }
    catch (e) { return true; }
  },
  get() {
    return '';
  }
})) {
  defaultPlayer = {
    userName,
    age,
    surname,
    isAdmin: false
  };
}

console.log(defaultPlayer);
```

When you omit a property value, it looks for a variable with the same name as the key. For example, `{x}` is the same as `{x: x}`. We can use the `with()` statement to have JavaScript check for properties of an object before looking for variables. Instead of a normal object, we'll define a `Proxy` that returns `''` for any variables that it doesn't see in the local environment (by testing for an exception when `eval`ing their name).

> ### ☠️ This is an obscene hack with nasty edge cases. Never use it. ☠️

Comment: Haha, I already wondered whether I should recommend just `const defaultPlayer = new Proxy({}, {get(t, key) { return typeof key=="symbol" ? t[key] : ""; }});` :D

Comment: @Bergi, also this is "an obscene hack"? Would you use it? Can I?

Comment: @JohnSam It's a less obscene hack than what Jeremy did, but still nasty. Don't use it.

Comment: @JohnSam I don't think there is really any decent way to accomplish what you're suggesting, no. :(